# How can I search for an executable in $PATH with a shell script

Tags: bash, executable

$PATH contains all directories which are searched, how can I find a particular executable, including wildcards, let's say I want to find all executables containing the string "sub"?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How are the directories in the $PATH variable separated? As usual with a colon: e.g. `/tmp/a:/tmp/b:/tmp/c`? Or by newline? Any other separator?

Answer (score 0):

```
for directory in $(echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'); do
    find $directory -type f -perm /111 -ls
done
```

Explanation:

```
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
```

Divide directories in $PATH to one directory each line.

```
find $directory -type f -perm /111 -ls
```

And loop through each directory and 'find' regular file(-type f) with permission executable by either owner or group or other(-perm /111), and list them (-ls).

Comment: Directories in `PATH` can contain whitespace and pattern metacharacters that will break this loop.

Comment: @chepner: Very true, but I just want to show how to approach this problem with a simple example, and not the real world implementation.

Answer (score -1):

If there is no need for wildcards, you can use the `which` command.
e.g.:

```
 which cat
/usr/bin/cat
```

Comment: Does not work for partial matches, which was the attention of my question.